# In Swift how to get memory back to normal after ARSCNView is removed? ARKIT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, arkit

I created game in ARKit, but everytime i run the game the memory usage increase. So after few plays game crashes. I have 3 controllers.

### ViewControllers

**FirstController -> SecondController -> ThirdController**

**FirstController** is where the app starts. **FirstController** calls **SecondController** after successful scanning 2D image in ARKit. Inside **SecondController** i have my ARKit game. The last **ThirdController** is used for displaying Score. It also have replay button. ( which is a segue to SecondController)

```
    class SecondController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {
        weak var scnScene: SCNScene!
        @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         sceneView.delegate = self
         sceneView.scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
         sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true;
         runStartTimer()
         startGame()
    }
        func gameOver() {
         let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
         defaults.set(score, forKey: "score")
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
                node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = nil
                node.geometry = nil
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                print("Object Deallocated =)")

            }
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameCompleted2", sender: self)

        }
    }
 }
```

I use segue to move from one view to another
for example:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameCompleted2", sender: self)
```

i have also tried using DEINIT , but it didint help

Comment: Are your view controllers in a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, 1st view is inside navigation controller and segue is modal (navigationview)->(HERE APP START)firstview->secondview->thirdview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so since you commented that your view controllers are inside a navigation controller this is what I assume is happening:

```
NavigationStack: [FirstViewController, SecondViewController]
*segue to ThirdViewController*
NavigationStack: [FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController]
*segue to SecondViewController*
NavigationStack: [FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController, SecondViewController]
*segue to ThirdViewController*
NavigationStack: [FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController]
```

And so on, recursively placing view controllers on top of each other. You can test this by printing `navigationController.viewControllers`.

An easy way to prevent this from happening is to present your ThirdViewController modally and dismiss it instead of segue to SecondViewController.

If you want to keep your animations the same as they are now then maybe editing the `navigationController.viewControllers` to remove items of the type that you just presented would work.

Comment: So to present my view self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) and to dismiss it  self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)?

Comment: What about unwind segue? Do they work the same? ( place viewcontroller on top of each other ) ?

Comment: I haven't used unwind segues recently but you can use those to go back to a previous view controller if I recall correctly, so yes that would work @ShadeToD

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i understand my problem now.